# Move list elements between two containers, combine with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would somehow assume that something like that has been asked but can't find anything.

1. At the beginning, all students are in the left list.
2. User can move students to the right list by clicking on the arrow
3. User can move students back to the original list
4. If group of students is too large, user can search with autocomplete
5. Pressing add (or enter) adds shifts the autocompleted student from left to right

[image]

I'm lost with where and how to start. What I've done so far.
Autocomplete works, there is no 'add' button yet.
The left list is populated.

What are good ways for:

- moving the students left and right
- connecting the lists with the autocomplete box

I'm not troubled by the serverside parts (PHP/mysql), but I rarely use js/jQuery and would be glad for any hints on how to approach this.

Comment: You mean like this? http://dpatri.com/technology/jquery/move-list-box-items-from-left-to-right-using-jquery/

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Because @Niklas' answer is way better and a working example.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler there's always multiple answers to questions like this. More approaches, the better. I personally always like to see how others do these kinds of things differently as well.

Comment: That doesn't mean that your answer can't contribute anything! Please undelete it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('#students li').live("click",function(){
   $(this).appendTo("#selectedStudents") 
});

$('#selectedStudents li').live("click",function(){
   $(this).appendTo("#students") 
});

$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#students li').filter(function(){
        if( $(this).text().toLowerCase() == $('#search').val().toLowerCase()){
            return true;
        }
    }).appendTo("#selectedStudents");
});
```

markup:

```
<input type="text" id="search" /><input type="button" value="add" id="add" />

<h4>students</h4>
<ul id="students">
    <li>Robert</li>
    <li>Steve</li>
    <li>Clara</li>
    <li>Beatrix</li>
    <li>Maximilian</li>
</ul>

<h4>selected students</h4>
<ul id="selectedStudents"></ul>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/3SrKL/

Comment: That looks like a great start, I'm amazed! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my quick thoughts:

First, create a move function.

```
function move(el, from, to){
    from.remove(el);
    to.append(el);
}
```

Then, add a click event to each arrow, which then grabs the element that contains the student. Then remove it from the left list and append it to the right list. Something like:

```
$('.student_arrow').click(function(){
    var student = $(this).parent(); // just a guess
    move($("#left"), $("#right"), student);
});
```

For connecting the autocomplete box, if each student element had a unique id that you can generate from the autocomplete box, you could then grab that element by id and move the element like above.

Comment: I suppose the only advantage oover @Niklas' answer is that it might be slightly faster (for larger lists) to generate an id for each student, on the fly for searching, instead of filtering the list.